# How can I stop Dashing from updating widgets outside of viewport

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, eventmachine, gridster, dashing

[image]I have set up a Home-automation dashboard using Shopify/Dashing as base.

Dashing uses Gridster.js to allocate the large amount of widgets I have in columns & pages. The pages are being switched with Dashing.cycleDashboards(). The widgets are binded to an EventSource socket with Batman.js (installed as Ruby Gem, which gets it's data from OpenHab through mqtt)

I've chosen not to create multiple dashboards because of the outdated browser the dashboard is running on and split them in gridster divs as said. This is where my question is about;

Although only one Gridster div is displayed at a time, all are being updated in the DOM. Because the browser is so unstable this takes up a lot of memory and browser chrashes.

**I'd like to stop Dashing from updating the hidden Gridster divs. Of course the div should get updated after switching to it.** *(After the switch I would like to execute state updates per widget with jQuery XHR calls.)*

Is the above possible? And if so, please point me in the right direction. What file(s) do I need to change? Sample code would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not fix this issue. I have rewritten the complete HTML structure to accomplish what I needed. Closing this thread!